# I am at the best block while downloading blockchain. Am I done?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

I'm very new to this and was following a tutorial to mine ethereum and it told me to install geth and once installed use geth -rpc to sync the blockchain. So ive been running that for the past 10hrs+ and i checked https://ethstats.net/ and apparently i am on the last block. Does this mean I am done? Thanks!

EDIT: This is the tutorial, and step 7 is the syncing part. http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/ethereum-mining-101-your-complete-guide_us_58b6e1eee4b02f3f81e44e9f

Comment: What was your intention? To download the entire data to your computer, if yes; yes your'e done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. When you run `geth` you are syncing the blockchain, downloading every block up until the recent block. The blockchain is made up of this series of blocks, with each block cryptographically tied to previous blocks.

https://ethstats.net/ reports the latest block, which at the time of posting this is 3,877,522. So if geth's current block matches that on ethstats, you've fully synced the blockchain. Congrats!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your fast response! Have a good one!

Comment: @Dynx and you as well! If you found my answer helpful, please mark it as accepted. If you feel especially generous, hit that upvote button :)

Comment: @Dynx __If you feel especially generous, hit that upvote button __

Comment: But if I understand correctly, if you want to mine ether, then you have to keep geth syncing, right?